# Trying to use posix_spawn() to create other processes but get a "permission denied error"

Tags: c, linux, debian

I am trying to create a process of a different executable file using posix_spawn(). The problem is I keep getting an error saying "spawn() failed: Permission denied". I don't know how to fix this. I am using Debian buster 10 if this helps. Do I need to change the permissions of the other file? If so how would I go about this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <spawn.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

extern char **environ

int main(void){

     char *args1[] = {"/home/filepath",NULL};
     int stat;
     pid_t pid;

     //this is where the code doesn't work
     if((stat1 = posix_spawn(&pid,"/home/filepath",NULL,NULL,args1,environ)) != 0){
          perror("spawn() failed");
     }else{
          printf("Proccess spawned, pid = %d\n",pid);
     }


return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: What is the file? Does it have exec permissions? Is it a binary or a script file?

Comment: Are you able to run `/home/filepath` directly on the command line?

Comment: It is a binary file and when I try and run it on the command line, it also says Permission denied.

Comment: _Side note:_ From the man page: _These  functions  were specified  by  POSIX  to  provide a standardized method of creating new processes on machines that **lack** the capability to support  the  `fork(2)` system  call.These functions are not meant to replace the `fork(2)` and `execve(2)` system calls_. Since you're using linux which _does_ have `fork`, why bother with this? So, use with care ...

Comment: You need to add exec permission to the target file. (e.g.) `chmod +x /home/filepath`. Then do: `ls -l /home/filepath`. You should see (e.g.) `-rwxr-xr-x. ...`

Comment: Yea I usually just use a fork because I never have this problem, but I am trying to use something new and learn from it.

Comment: You can't call execve on a file without exec privileges either. So this problem is with your binary and not with `spawn`

Comment: I figured it out. I just used gcc file.c -o file on the command line and it then allowed me to use the posix_spawn(). I am still new to Linux, but thank you guys for the replies.